# how to skip specific lines in awk and print the remaining

Tags: awk

how can I read only lines: 3,9,12, 15 from the  file containing the ff lines.
The idea is whenever I get x and  y , I wanted to print the last line among lines containing x and y.
What I meant is , for example , if I have awk script like : BEGIN { name = $2; value=$3; } { if(name == x && value==y && the scan reaches at lines 3, 9, 12 and 15) printf("hello world") }. what expression can I use instead of "the scan reaches at lines 3, 9 12 and 15"

```
1 x y
2 x y 
3 x y 
4 a d
5 e f
6 x y
7 x y
8 x y
9 x y
10 g f
11 x y
12 x y
13 p r
14 w c
15 x y
16 a z
```

Comment: Lines 2 and 3 in your input have trailing spaces is this really the case?

Answer (score 3):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]+ x y$/{a=$0;f=1;next}f{print a;f=0}' file
3 x y
9 x y
12 x y
15 x y
```

One way without `awk`:

```
$ tac file | uniq -f1 | fgrep -w 'x y' | tac
3 x y
9 x y
12 x y
15 x y
```

Comment: Hmm, the `awk` gives me line 1,9,12,15.  Its seems to be correct done, so not sure what is wrong.  My `awk` gives correct lines.  EDIT: `tac` gives me 1,3,9,12,15 so its some wrong too.  I do use Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You have trailing whitespace in your file.. try `cat -E file`. I am more stringent with whitespace, may or may not be useful for the OP  http://ideone.com/puI2Ss

Comment: Yes, there was space behind line 2 and 3 in roberas post, removing them and it worked. I did not see this in my solution due to use of `$2$3`.  Se your solution may have been written `awk '$2$3=="xy" {a=$0;f=1;next}f{print a;f=0}'` to be more robust for spaces.

Comment: My solution could be changed many ways to allow for whitespace however I don't think it's a good idea to have trailing whitespace as demonstrated here scripts will fail in cryptic ways. My editor is set up to remove unnecessary whitespace so I didn't pick up the fact the input wasn't clean.

Comment: I use `emacs` I'm not sure how configurable `nano` is. Both `vi` and `emacs` are very customizable and powerful, I can be a steep learning curve but in the longer run you will be better off switching.

Answer (score 1):

Some like this?

```
awk 'a=="xy" && $2$3!="xy" {print b} {a=$2$3;b=$0}' file
3 x y
9 x y
12 x y
15 x y
```

Comment: this works fine,  its something I am going to use inside awk script , not on command line...

Comment: No problem, this works fine in a shell script.  You may then redirect output to a file or a variable.  File: `awk 'a=="xy" && $2$3!="xy" {print b} {a=$2$3;b=$0}' file >result` or Variable: `result=$(awk 'a=="xy" && $2$3!="xy" {print b} {a=$2$3;b=$0}' file)`

Comment: But is there a way that I can use this as a condition, i.e if( $2 == x && $3 == y) && the scan reaches at lines 3, 9 12 and 15,  print "sth else" , instead of the lines themselves

Comment: You can read variable like this `awk '$2==x && $3==y {a=$0;f=1;next} f {print a;f=0}' x="$var1" y="$var2" file` It then uses variable stored inn `var1` and `var2` en test the `file` (using a combination of my solution and sudo_Os solution)

Comment: Careful - this will fail when $2 is "xy" and $3 is "", for example.

Comment: Correct.  Data in file have to be at the for of "data space value x space value y"

Comment: What I meant is , for example , if I have awk script like : BEGIN { name = $2; value=$3; } {  if(name == x && value==y && the scan reaches at lines 3, 9, 12 and 15)  printf("hello world") }. what expression can I use instead of "the scan reaches at lines 3, 9 12 and 15"

Answer (score -2):

You need to use two while loops here one to check the line and another to iterate. Something like this. Hope that helps

String line = "";
        int i = 0;

```
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\readline.txt"));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            i++;
            if (line.charAt(0) == 'x' && line.charAt(2) == 'y') {
                System.out.println("Line containg Y and Y");
                String searchline = line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {   //Iterate untill you find the last line of X and Y
                    i++;         //To keep count of the line read
                    if (line.charAt(0) == 'x' && line.charAt(2) == 'y') {
                        searchline = line;
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                System.out.println("Printing the  line ::" + (i - 1) + ":: containing X and Y::::::::" + searchline);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Caught::::");
    }
}
```